# How to record guitar into FL Studio 21

Tags: guitar, recording, fl-studio

I have an audio interface hooked up to studio monitors and I have set everything up (Real life amplifier with 1/4" output wired to the 1/4" audio interface input). I see an output as a recording in the playlist arranger (shown in the included screenshot) but there is no sound coming out of my studio monitors.

[image: recording but no sound]

Edit: OK I fixed the output problem. I was choosing output for a channel that wasn't scanning for input. BUT now I face a new problem. The guitar plays out of time and it lags. How do I fix this? Anyone know? I'm using the FL Studio DAW.

Comment: I think the issue might have more to do with your hardware configuration than with FL Studio.  It could help if you indicate what interface you are using.  Is FL Studio set to echo input to output?

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it. Any way to get lag out of my live recording? It makes the guitar virtually unplayable the lag is so bad.

Comment: If you have lag, it's most likely due to the configuration of your interface.  Without knowing what you have we can't give a good answer.

Comment: I have a Scarlett Solo by Focusrite.